# Discord: Prevent a new user from seeing messages sent before he was invited to the server

Tags: permissions, discord

Is there way to restrict a new user in a discord server from seeing all conversations which have happened before he joined the server?

I see a "Read message history" permission but the description doesn't seem to fit. It's far too restrictive

> Read Message History — Allows for the reading of message history. When this permission is denied, a user that exits and reloads Discord or refreshes it with CTRL+R will not see the content sent in channels from before the the reload. Even their own messages will not show. As long as the application is running anything sent during that time will still be available to read

So it even restricts the user from seeing messages which were sent after he joined but not in the current session.

Is there any other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not easily at least.

If you have few people joining and there are only a few channels you need to censor, you may be able to work around it. When this issue came up in one of my servers, we created a new #general channel and archived the old one under a different name, restricting who can see it with roles. This has a downside (other than the obvious time sink to set it up); you can't easily search for "general" chats, since the messages are divided between two channels.